# Помогите загнать массив в БД MYSQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

есть 2 инпута (тип текст) 
1-й инпут Любимая Игра
2-й инпут Любимое Оружие в Игре
есть кнопка button (Добавить Еще)
Она ч\з javascript добавляет еще 2 инпута - такие же
У нас получается массив
Массив выводится очень на ура
Вот код:

```
echo  $_POST['map'];
echo "</span></p>";

$persons = $_POST['person'];

foreach ($persons as $person) {
    echo '<p>Любимая Игра - <span>'.$person['game'].'</span>,  Любимое Оружие - <span>'.$person['weapon'].'</span><hr/></p>';
}
```

Вопрос! Как загнать за раз этот массив в БД MYSQL (поля у таблицы - id,game,weapon)?

Comment: чтобы загнать массив ,объект в БД можно его превратить в строку.Используйте JSON.

Comment: это как реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Команда MySQL интересует? Написал ниже, без валидации без ничего. Как пример подойдет?

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` SET `game`=$person['game'], `weapon`=$person['weapon'];
```

Предполагаю, что поле id - auto_increment primary key.

Comment: так заганяет последнеи данные введенные в $person['game'], `weapon`=$person['weapon']; , а не весь массив!

Comment: Так поставьте внутри foreach

Comment: где именно можно пример?

Comment: foreach ($persons as $person) {
    echo '<p>Любимая Игра - <span>'.$person['game'].'</span>,  Любимое Оружие - <span>'.$person['weapon'].'</span><hr/></p>';
mysql_query('INSERT INTO `table_name` SET `game`= "' . $person['game'] . '", `weapon`="' . $person['weapon'] . '";');
}

Comment: так все работает, только есть одно но, в базу заливаются массив только тогда, когда он чисто из цифр, если в массиве символ, в БД инфа не поступает!

Comment: прочитайте про экранирование кавычками текстовых переменных при добавлении их в таблицу!

Comment: get_magic_quotes_gpc() ?

Comment: нет.... всетаки почитайте про [INSERT](http://expange.ru/e/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C_%D0%B2_%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83_(MySQL)) в MySQL

    INSERT INTO `table_name` SET `game`='{$person['game']}', `weapon`='{$person['weapon']}';

это самые азы.....

Comment: Можно использовать `prepared statements`, или, по крайней мере, PDO вообще.

Comment: @Construct это будет высший пилотаж :)